# Python adding outputs from a loop to an variable

Tags: python

The output I want to have is like:

```
the result is 8

the result is 16

the result is 24

the result is 32

the result is 40
```

So I do:

```
final = ''

for each_one in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    result = 'the result is ' + str(each_one * 8)
    final.join(result)
    final.join('\n')

print final
```

But it doesn't work out. How can I adjust it?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to build a single `result` string with all of your lines in it, or could you just do a `print(result)` within the `for` loop?

Comment: @Blckknght, I need them in that way i.s.o separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing `str.join`; it actually works like

```
"x".join(["A", "B", "C"])  # => "AxBxC"
```

`.join` expects an iterable (ie a list or generator) of strings. If you pass it a single string, it will treat it as a list of characters:

```
"x".join("ABC")            # => "AxBxC"
```

What you actually need to do is

```
lines = []
for num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    line = 'the result is ' + str(num * 8)
    lines.append(line)
print('\n\n'.join(lines))
```

which gives

```
the result is 8

the result is 16

the result is 24

the result is 32

the result is 40
```

Answer (score 3):

```
final = ''

for each_one in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    final += ('the result is ' + str( each_one * 8 )+'\n\n')

print final
```

I believe you are mixing join function with concatenation.

Not saying it would be impossible to do it with join,but
your code resembles usage of string concatenation.

Learn more about join [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

Comment: thanks. it's very difficult to decide to choose yours or the below. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
print '\n\n'.join(['the result is {}'.format(each_one * 8) for each_one in range(1, 6)])
```

Comment: range(1,6) would be faster, i was going to put that in but i felt my answer wouldn't have been as clear. nicely done

Answer (score 1):

```
final = '\n'.join(["The result is " + str(num * 8) for num in [1,2,3,4,5]])
print(final) #or "print final" if Python 2
```

EDIT: if you want a line break in between each line, replace the '\n' with '\n\n'

EDIT#2:

The join method takes an iterable as its argument, which a list comprehension to a list counts. Any string calling the join method will concatenate the string in between the elements of the iterable in the join method argument. So a '\n' will appear concatenated to each element in the list I made via a list comprehension.

List comprehensions are key components of the language. They allow to dynamically create lists and can be useful for creating lists on-the-fly.
What it is saying, for each number in the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`, do `"The result is " + str(num * 8)` on it, then take all the results and make a list out of it.

List comprehensions are great if you intend for a list object to be created. For example, you can use them to filter out a current list:

```
stringList = ["yes","no","yesterday"]
filtered = [item for item in stringList if "yes" in item]
#result is: ["yes", "yesterday"]
```

They are commonly misused as performing an operation over elements of an iterable, with no desire to have a list object. In that specific case, a simple for loop would be better.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to write this to be a bit easier and cleaner, if you'd like.

You can simply do:

```
for number in range(1,6):
    print("The result is "+str(number*8))
```

Which outputs:

```
The result is 8
The result is 16
The result is 24
The result is 32
The result is 40
```